# How to use slash commands in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, command, slash

I am trying to make a discord bot which gives Google drive sharable link using slash command

When I type "/bot notes" it should display these choices

```
sub= ["ac","cal","emi","pc"]
```

it should display these sub choices for respective  items

```
ac=["cat1","cat2","cb1","cb2"]
```

and similarly for others too it should display the sub chioces
after choosing any sub command the bot should give the link.
But the problem is that how should I use slash command and provide choices and sub-choices ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not sure what exactly you're getting at here. If you're talking about arguments, then slash commands come with autocomplete.

You could start by making a function

```
async def notes(ctc: discord.AutocompleteContext):
    return ["ac","cal","emi","pc"]
```

and then passing this as an autocomplete like this:

```
bot = discord.Bot()
@bot.slash_command(description="test", autocomplete=notes)
```

Comment: Can you tell me the source from where I can learn use of slash command

Comment: If you're using pycord slash commands, check here for examples:
https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord/tree/master/examples/app_commands